# What am I missing about using jQuery with Angular's $digest method?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I am having trouble understanding using jQuery with Angular's digest cycle.

I am using an ng-repeat= to load content. the content (using $compile) ends up being a div with with two child divs and several grandchild elements. after loading the arrary for the ng-repeat, I want to use jQuery's children.each() like so:

```
callBack = function(index) {
    var objParent = $('#' + $scope.panes[index].windID); //entire window
    var objChild = [];
    //objChild[0] = title bar
    //objChild[1] = contentpane
    objParent.children().each(function(i){
        objChild[i] = $(this);
    });
    //more code
}
```

The problem is that as my open window method got larger with more features, somehow Angular's digest started working differently. What I mean is that before I added my maximize/restore/minimize methods and buttons to match, when my controller got to the code above, the window was already digested through scope and showed in the dom (although hidden with {display: none} for jQuery's fade in) meaning that the above code worked.

However now that there is more going on to be digested, when it gets to that point the digest is not complete, and the child finder fails since that DOM has not been updated yet. I have to use $timeout, and I increasingly have to increase the time. I have to wait around 600ms right now, and I feel that is to slow from icon click to window showing.

Now, If I add a $scope.$apply() right before the $timeout(), it acts like it's just forcing the digest to hurry up. I can reduce the time back to 0ms, and everything works instantly. Yet I get a digest in progress error. I thought the $timeout waited for the end of the digest anyways?

I've tried various methods, even $$postDigest, but the only thing that seems to work is forcing an $apply resulting in a digest in progress error that the end user will never see nor even care about since it actually makes it all work. That would not me so much of a problem, but it bugs me because after opening and closing my window "panes" the digest in progress error can multiply in the console.

Here's a link to a little bit older version: [AkadineWebOS](http://www.crawfordcomputing.com/AkadineWebOS/)

The app is more jQuery than Angular, I'm just using Angular for it's http module and to make it easy to push and splice my window array and let the ng-repeat magic handle the dom. jQuery does all the heavy lifting with dragging, resizing, fadein/out, centering windows on open, and most everything else.

So here is my question: Can someone please explain to me what I am missing about the way that Angular's digest works?

Comment: Please don't do this inside of a controller.  It's better to do this inside of a directive.  I'd be able to suggest a link function if I were able to understand a bit more about what kind of DOM you're trying to get and what piece of DOM you're trying to build out.

Comment: what is it you are trying to accomplish by falling back to jQuery like this?   Your question describes some really abstract processes without a lot of detail so it's hard to follow what you are experiencing, but it really stands out that you are using `$compile` and jQuery methods;  In the *vast* majority of cases `$compile` is unnecessary, and certainly mixing jQuery with angular has it's own considerations.....

Comment: it *feels like* you might be describing a case where something in angular is async, and though angular can update the DOM, jQuery doesn't know the process is async and is trying to access the DOM immediately.  This isn't a problem of `$digest`, specifically.

Comment: Yes Claies I think your right. If you type that up as an answer I'll vote it up. An older version of my project (no digest errors, but no min/max/restore) can be found                                                           [here](http://www.crawfordcomputing.com/AkadineWebOS/)                                   and that should give you more of an idea. You can drag and resize the windows. It's meant to be a universal admin backend to every website I am contracted to make, and ultimately a full CMS system like SalesForce.

Comment: The reason you are getting the "digest in progress" error is because `$timeout()` by default triggers a `$scope.$apply()` call (which initiates a `$digest()` from the `$rootScope` down) after the delayed function is run. You can prevent this by passing `false` as the third parameter to the `$timeout()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As Claise said, jQuery is not asyc like angular. I actually just had to change the $timeout() to a plain ol' setTimeout(), basically asycing my jQuery callback. Now it works great!